# how to save a result from a mongodb query into a javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, mongodb

there are some questions here regarding how to save a result from a query into a javascript varialbe, but I'm just not able to implement them. The point is that I have a much difficult query, so this question is, in my opinion, unique.

Here is the problem. I have a collection namend "drives" and a key named "driveDate". I need to save 1 variable with the smallest date, and other with the biggest date.

The query for the smallest date is:

```
> db.drives.find({},{"_id":0,"driveDate":1}).sort({"driveDate":1}).limit(1)
```

The result is:

```
{ "driveDate" : ISODate("2012-01-11T17:24:12.676Z") }
```

how dan I save this to a variable, can I do something like:

```
tmp = db.drives.find({},{"_id":0,"driveDate":1}).sort({"driveDate":1}).limit(1)
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Where is your query being run?  Is it on the server side?  Or is it being run on the client end?

Comment: @Ivan, the query is direct on the mongo console. (with the command "mongo"). The DB is locally installed on my machine. I already figured out how to make it. thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to do this in the shell:

```
 tmp = db.drives.find({}, {_id:0, driveDate:1}).sort({driveDate:1}).limit(1).toArray()[0]
```

`find` returns a cursor that you need to iterate over to retrieve the actual documents.  Calling `toArray` on the cursor converts it to an array of docs.

Comment: I am unsure if `sort()` works on `findOne` since it does not return a cursor as such the chain will have no function of `sort()`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I keep getting this error: "Sun Dec  2 21:58:13 TypeError: db.drives.findOne({}, {_id:0, driveDate:1}).sort is not a function (shell):1"... somehow findOne can't work with sort

Comment: @otmezger Sorry about that, Sam's right, there doesn't seem to be a way to sort with `findOne` in the shell.  See updated answer.

Comment: I'd like to share my wtf experience. I was doing `let tmp = db.collection.aggregate(...).map(doc => doc._id)` in IntelliJ IDEA DataGrip to later use the variable in another query `$match: { "foo": { $in: tmp } }`. But I faced `WriteAbortedException; NotSerializableException: 
 TruffleStackTraceElement` error. The solution was to append `.toArray()` as in your example. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

After some time figuring out, I got the solution. here it is, for future reference:

```
var cursor = db.drives.find({},{"_id":1}).sort({"driveDate":1}).limit(1)
```

Then I can get the document from the cursor like this

```
var myDate = cursor.next()
```

That's it. Thanks for your help